# Accessing mobile virtual keyboard using appium

Tags: java, appium

I am using appium for mobile automation in which I came across a situation where I need to click on the `"Done"` button on the mobile virtual keyboard after providing the input. How is it possible in appium using `WebDriver`?

Comment: There is already a topic connected with keyboard "done" button. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35412975/5415807

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe the solution from @Slavo is deprecated in appium. Though the adb commands with the same key-event should work i.e

   `adb shell input keyevent 66`
2. In most of the cases your input is mostly a single liner e.g. performing a search. In which case you can make change to a previous line as :

   `WebElement myTextView  =  <find your text-view>
   myTextView.sendKeys("your-text/n"); // "/n" as a new line in java`
3. You can also hide the keyboard and perform the actions using other screen widgets thereon. Like :

   `driver.hideKeyboard();
   WebElement otherGoodToGoButton = <find other useful button/widget>
   otherGoodToGoButton.click();`
4. Clicking screen coordinates using `TouchActions` is also a way but I wouldn't suggest using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidekeyboard function

```
driver.hideKeyboard()
```

Thanks,
Sadik

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a lot of trouble with the done checkbox on the native numpad, and none of the keyevent keycodes worked. In the end, this script worked for us:

```
$driver.execute_script("mobile:performEditorAction", {'action'=>'done'})
```

In whatever language you use ... execute a script 'mobile:performEditorAction' and send it a hash {'action' => 'done'} .

Answer (score 0):

This solution in `JavaScript` using `wd` worked for me:

```
return driver.waitForElementById(<elementId>).type(<text to type>).click()
               .execute( "mobile: performEditorAction", { "action": "search" } );
```

This allowed me to find a text field, input some text, and submit a search command (same as clicking the search icon in the keyboard).

Of course, you have to replace `<elementId>` and `<text to type>` with the proper values. See http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/ for details on "mobile: performEditorAction".

You can replace "search" with "done" or various other commands found at the link above.